# Flutter integration tests won't run

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to write some integration tests using the flutter driver based off of the example here: https://flutter.io/testing/. I am able to get the app to deploy, but all I get back is awaiting for app response.
I'm really not sure what else to do as it just sits and waits.
Here's what I see in the terminal.

```
 flutter drive --target=test_driver/home_category_list_scroll.dart
 Using device Sampson's iPhone.
 Starting application: test_driver/home_category_list_scroll.dart
 Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified 
 development team in Xcode project: QDCF25JLN2
 Running pod install...                                       7.2s
 Starting Xcode build...                                          
 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                   13.0s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                  7.5s
 Xcode build done.                                           27.6s
 Installing and launching...                                      
 flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:54774/
 00:00 +0: scrolling performance test (setUpAll)
 [info ] FlutterDriver: Connecting to Flutter application at 
 http://127.0.0.1:54270
 [info ] FlutterDriver: Waiting for application to start
 [info ] FlutterDriver: Waiting for application to start
 [info ] FlutterDriver: Waiting for application to start
```

Here's are the first few lines of the test.

```
void main() {
group('scrolling performance test', () {
FlutterDriver driver;

setUpAll(() async {
  // Connects to the app
  driver = await FlutterDriver.connect(dartVmServiceUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:54270');
});

tearDownAll(() async {
  if (driver != null) {
    // Closes the connection
    driver.close();
  }
});

test('measure', () async {
```

Flutter Doctor output:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v0.5.8-pre.56, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E202, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.0)
 ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
 ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2017.1.6)
[!] VS Code (version 1.24.1)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Thank you for any ideas you can give me.

Comment: `flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:54774/` but you have hard coded the vm service url to `http://127.0.0.1:54270`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have been struggling with that. When I leave out the hard coded url. The call to get the url, Platform.environment['VM_SERVICE_URL'], always returns null. I have been having trouble figuring out what the VM_SERVICE_URL should be. Any thoughts on what the dartVmServiceUrl should be. Thank you for any help you can give!!

Comment: Does it work if you just leave that out?

Comment: No it does not work. I get the message:

`Could not determine URL to connect to application. Either the VM_SERVICE_URL environment variable should be set, or an explicit URL should be provided to the FlutterDriver.connect() method.`

Comment: `driver = await FlutterDriver.connect();` should find the default observatory. If not, I would, as a sanity test, create a new default project (the counter app) and confirm the provided integration test runs. Then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if an Xcode build config is set that may be overriding the target file `flutter drive` was running? I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26968#issuecomment-485970830) and setting flavors worked on the integration test for them.

Answer (score 0):

use flutter run and look at the url that returns in the console where the app is running, that is the one you should use in your dartVmServiceUrl parameter

source: https://medium.com/flutter-community/blazingly-fast-flutter-driver-tests-5e375c833aa